# Several forms logic, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm still learning Laravel, as what I'm trying to accomplish at the moment is the following logic:

-An User submits a form-> The form input is saved into DB, and is 'sent' to another User who can then validate it->I save into the DB if the state is validated or not, and inform the User who sent the form.

I know this is not too hard, but I'm doing it as I learn Laravel, so I'm coming up with a few 'problems'.

First of all, I do have quite a lot of forms, and I did get the Post logic working. At the moment I'm not working with the Database yet, so I tested the Forms with SESSION, to make sure the data was being saved.

So my first question is: is it best practice in this case to keep all form logic into one Controller? Like the following(this is working with two different forms) (session is there only for testing purposes)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function geralSuggest(Request $request)
    {

        $name = $request->input('obs');

        return redirect('sugestoes');
    }

    public function GD(Request $request)
    {

        session_start();

        $name = $request->input('nome');
        $cc = $request->input('cartao');
        $array = array ($name, $cc);
        $_SESSION["testPostSection"] = $array;        

        return redirect('declaracaogd');   
    }
}
```

Secondly, I have some forms where the user can add inputs. Lets say one input is for the name, and the user has a button that when he clicks he adds another name input, so he can input many names at once. This is done by Javascript on my side. What I'm wondering is how will I save this inputs, since I 'don't know' how many "names" the user will be submitting. I was thinking a for or foreach loop, where I would check with "isset", but I'm not sure if it will work. I will be testing this when I get to it regardless, and I'm sure I'll figure it out, but if you know a good logic for this and could point me in the right path, it would be appreciated.

Lastly, about my general logic, for User validation, from what I read on Laravel documentation, I think Events will be what makes the trigger to 'warn' the second User that he needs to validate a form, is that correct?

I'm sorry if I'm asking "too much at once" or if these are very basic questions. I just wanted to make sure that I'm going in the right direction.

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if I understand your system 100% correctly. But it seems you are trying to make a human validation program? So 1 users submits data and another users validates this data. In this case I would do this in 2 seperate controllers. Laravels explenation on controllers states: "Controllers can group related request handling logic into a single class." Providing data or validating data are 2 different things. But this isnt a strict rule.

For the second question. Laravel has an all() method. `$input = $request->all();` will give you an array will all request data. After that you could loop over the array and insert it into a db or the storage method you want.

Edit: another way to handle this if you could have multiple names could be:

```
// View
<input type="text" name="names[]">
<input type="text" name="names[]">

// Controller
$request->names; // This is an array of values
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-the-values-of-dynamically-generated-inputs

And events are indeed the way to go if you want to send a message. so you could fire an event as soon as the data is submitted. And one of the listeners would send a email or something like that

Comment: Thanks a ton! Yes, that is indeed what I was looking for. 
For the first question, just to make sure: I make one controller where I have all my submit logic(and in this controller I have my submit logic for all my forms in different functions), and another one for the user validating the form, right?
The $request->all() seems to be exactly what I was looking for, way simpler than going through loops. I will test it but seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Well its somewhat about personal pref. They way I would do it is 1 controller to show the form and process the data when submitted. and another controller to show the validation view and to process the validation. But if your prefer to do this in 1 controller for some reason thats your good right!